# Process being killed by a third party application (Sprint Smartview)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process, kill

Recently two users of our software from the same company started experiencing random closures (no error messages, crash dialogs, quit dialogs etc).  We were able to isolate what the two systems had in common down to a particular piece of software (a mobile broadband device manager).  When this software is running our software randomly closes within a ~2 minute time frame.  If we exit the broadband manager our software runs indefinitely without issue.

I can think of no reason why there would be any interaction between our software and theirs.  The network is not accessed by our software and the broadband modem isn't even plugged in in any case.

We provided a work around for the customer (run our software as Administrator or exit the mobile broadband manager before running our software) but we want to resolve the problem so they don't need to worry about doing either of these things.

I attached a remote debugger to our software but I wasn't quite sure where to look to investigate exactly how our software is dying.  Debugging just ends with exit code 0 when our process is ended.

My question is, how can I investigate how/why a Win32 process is being killed and what can I do to prevent it from happening?

Edit: I opened the broadband manager and the DLLs it uses in a hex editor and there references to an executable with the exact same name as ours.  So I guess that's the link. Renaming our executable fixes the problem for our users but not, unfortunately, the stupidity of the Sprint SmartView.

**Edit**: To help the rare other developer this hits: If your executable is named `phoenix.exe` and your end users are running Sprint SmartView, that's why your program is randomly dying.  Renaming your executable will resolve this (or spend several months of your life trying to figure out who to notify at Sprint to get this truly resolved).  The file that mentions `phoenix.exe` specifically is `WwanCoreSdk.dll`.

Comment: if 'the broadband modem isn't even plugged in' can't you uninstall the driver, and then tell its authors that they've got problems?

Comment: @tomfumb : Uninstall the driver from clients' computers? I certainly hope not!

Comment: @ildjarn - make them do it, and why not? If a software vendor discovered that you had faulty (or even worse - malicious) software on your machine that you weren't using wouldn't you uninstall it?

Comment: @tomfumb : Removing software from a computer you don't own is _beyond_ immoral.

Comment: @ildjarn please take the time to read before you comment - 'make them do it' is quite clear

Comment: @tomfumb It's occurs even when it isn't plugged in/in use but they do use the mobile broadband when they are away from the office so uninstalling isn't an option unfortunately (that was the first thing we asked).

Comment: @tomfumb : Apparently I read your comments better than you did. "*can't you uninstall the driver*" -- no, you can't (morally).

Comment: @ildjarn: "Removing software from a computer you don't own is beyond immoral" - I seem to have to do exactly that every time I visit my dad... ;)

Comment: @eco what kind of software is your software? Is it a driver?  Or just a regular app?  Also do you access any system resources in your software?

Comment: @tomfumb : It wasn't obvious (to me anyway) that your second comment was a clarification of the first. My working hours are certainly no concern of yours.

Comment: Evidently yes that is the link. Can you let us know what the name of the EXE being killed was so we can not call ours that?  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is 32 bit, try to check out [WinAPIOverride32](http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/winapioverride32/). It will show you all syscalls done by program, so If you are able to time killing your program correctly in log from mentioned manager, it should make it easier to explain why it is happening.

Comment: Great idea. Had I not figured it out I would have been trying this next.

Comment: I'm going to accept this because (even though I figured it out on a hunch) it would have most likely led me down the right path to figure out what was going on.

Comment: Hmmm who is just kiling any process called 'phoenix.exe' without checking if it is what you want to kill? At least some executable path test should be done before terminating. I have even thought that renaming exefile might help, but then I thought "come on, who would be so dumb to produce such a berserk app?" ;)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately,

> A process cannot prevent itself from being terminated.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: That answer seems correct and philosophical at the same time.

Comment: I don't think there's any argument over *preventing* the process from getting killed. I was under the impression that the OP just wanted to find out who's doing it.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: My answer was to the OP's question "...what can I do to prevent it from happening?", i.e. nothing.

Comment: Tell that to the last virus that infected my system.